# Как сделать ссылки на табы в одном диве а содержимое табов в другом диве?

Tags: html, css

Здаравствуйте! Табы находятся в одном диве а нужно чтобы ссылки табов были в одном диве, а меняющийся контент в другом диве.
Как реализовать примерно такую конструкцию?

> ```
> <div class="navigation"><a href="#t1">Таб1</a><a href="#t2">Таб2</a><div>
> <div class="content">
>      <div id="tabs">
>           <div id="t1">Content1</div>
>           <div id="t2">Content2</div>
>      </div>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего, конечно, не изобретать велосипед: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Но если всё же есть желание написать такое самостоятельно, то всё (почти) тоже просто: в ссылке у вас есть атрибут href, который является готовым селектором для выбора нужного блока с контентом:

```
$('.navigation a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#tabs '+$(this).attr('href')).show().siblings().hide()
})
```

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: простите? http://jsfiddle.net/54AUJ/

Comment: А, а как по умолчанию один таб сделать видимым?

Comment: без понятия. Кто-то где-то говорил про какой-то css, про display:block, но что всё это значит… беда-печаль, это ж документацию читать надо на такие сложные вещи :(

Comment: Туплю, весь день так. Большое спасибо! Добра вам!